# Creating a combination data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do the following:

```
A B
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

using data.table, but I am not sure how to exclude the already used numbers cumulatively.

Comment: You can start with just `combn(1:4, 2)`

Comment: Or using `CJ` i.e. `CJ(1:4, 1:4)[V1<V2]`

Comment: Generally, it's better to explain in words what you're looking for (instead of saying "do the following"). Luckily, folks guessed what you were after in this case...